# Restrict sed to delete a single matching line only

Tags: regex, bash, sed

My goal is very simple. Given a file with data:

```
$ cat yes
ayaz
khan
ayaz
ahmed
ayaz
something
ayaz
```

I wish to delete, using `sed`, the first line that matches the expression `ayaz`. (*Of course, this is sample data, and in real data, the first occurrence of the expression can be on any given line, not merely the first. I would want the line with the first occurrence of the expression to be removed.*)

However, with `sed`, I cannot figure out how to tell `sed` to give up after matching and deleting the first occurrence.

```
$ sed '/ayaz/d' yes
khan
ahmed
something
```

I've looked at countless examples and, unless have kept overlooking it, have not been able to figure out a way to do it. Any helpful pointers will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Do your system not have `awk`?

Comment: @Jotne: It does. It also has Perl and Python. However, I'm interested in finding a way to do it with `sed`.

Comment: Ok, at the moment there are no portable  `sed` solution posted, so you need `gnu sed`. Both the `awk` posted should be working on most system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `sed` may work on non `gnu sed`, but it leaves a blank line:

```
sed '/ayaz/{s///;:a;n;ba}' yes

khan
ayaz
ahmed
ayaz
something
ayaz
```

---

A shorter version of the `gnu sed` (but still longer than my `awk`)

```
sed '0,/ayaz/{//d;}' yes
khan
ayaz
ahmed
ayaz
something
ayaz
```

---

An other version (did not work on my busybox system):

```
sed 'x;/./{x;b};x;/ayaz/{h;d}' yes
khan
ayaz
ahmed
ayaz
something
ayaz
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jotne. Because I am on GNU systems, I decided to go with the second option.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sed '0,/ayaz/{/ayaz/d}' yes
```

Comment: For info, fine for GNU sed, will not work on POSIX one (just a limitation about the `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another `awk` (even shorter than the `sed`), and should work on most system.

```
awk '!/ayaz/||f++' yes
khan
ayaz
ahmed
ayaz
something
ayaz
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk it is simpler:

```
awk '!p && /ayaz/{p=1;next}1' file
khan
ayaz
ahmed
ayaz
something
ayaz
```